# Keep getting the error "missing right parenthesis" when trying to create Oracle table

Tags: oracle, ddl

I have the following code in SQL developer, and when i try and run the code to create the table, it fails on this line: 'exists_flag varchar2(1) y/n,'

```
 create table moulds
 (mould_id  number,
 mould_type varchar2(50),
 mould_description varchar2(240),
 exists_flag varchar2(1) y/n,
 locate_id  number,
 );
```

Can anyone see what's wrong with the line and why it keeps saying "missing right parenthesis" ?

```
 create table moulds
 (mould_id  number,
 mould_type varchar2(50),
 mould_description varchar2(240),
 check (exists_flag in ( 'y', 'n' )),
 locate_id  number,
 PRIMARY KEY (mould_id)
 );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace `y/n` by

```
check (exists_flag in ( 'y', 'n' ))
```

Comment: @Raphael Althaus Ive changed it and now i get 'invalid identifier' Please see original post for updated code.